# ShareActionProvider is not working accurately with support library in android

Tags: android, shareactionprovider

I am stuck on this hectic bug and couldn't fix after checking almost all the related questions here.
I have an app in which I am using SharActionProvider in my action bar for sharing some content with support of AppCompat library.
Here is my related code:
in activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.cafe__detail, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.share);
        mShareActionProvider =  (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item); 
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private Intent getDefaultIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "testing text");
        intent.setType("text/plain");       
        return intent;
    }
```

here is all imports.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

I am also extending my activity from ActionBarActivity.
Here is xml in manu.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:MyApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.MyApp.Cafe_Detail" >



    <item android:id="@+id/share"
          android:title="@string/action_share"
          android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_holo_dark"
          MyApp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          MyApp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />    
</menu>
```

now everything is,when i click on share button list of available applications shows but when i click one of them, app crashes. and null point exceptions throws.
Log cat shows this

```
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserView.updateAppearance(ActivityChooserView.java:510)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserView.access$400(ActivityChooserView.java:66)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserView$3.onChanged(ActivityChooserView.java:247)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserView$1.onChanged(ActivityChooserView.java:127)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel.addHisoricalRecord(ActivityChooserModel.java:749)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserModel.chooseActivity(ActivityChooserModel.java:488)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActivityChooserView$Callbacks.onItemClick(ActivityChooserView.java:553)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-14 18:30:01.942: E/AndroidRuntime(4818):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

after crashing once, it even not opens the activity, and throws the same exception.
Anybody will you please help me?